# Tracking a memory leak triggered by using a parameter in PRISM Navigation

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, prism

My View-model implements `IDisposable`.  When I pass it as a parameter to a Prism `RequestNavigate` call, it never gets disposed.  Not even when I force Garbage Collection.   I cannot understand why.  I don't think there's anything wrong with Prism, but I cannot get past this point to narrow it down further.

The Navigation code that causes the leak (of `ScanContextVm`) is here

```
void AnalyzeContext(ScanContextVm ctx) // 'ctx' Leaks if I put it in the parameters
{
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate("Main", "Analyze", 
        new NavigationParameters {{"Scan", ctx}}); // Parameters
});
```

But if I just change that last line to comment out the parameter, there is no leak and I see the finalizer being called

```
        new NavigationParameters { /*{"Scan", ctx}*/}); // Parameters
```

The navigation target never even *touches* the parameters.  So it's not like they're being cached or anything.

```
public  void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext ctx) {}
```

How do I know this object leaks in one case and not the other? Because I've put log statements and breakpoints in its constructor and finalizer. I've seen the output and been stopped in the debugger.  And I've added a few key spots in my app to regularly, manually trigger GC, just to try to force the issue (Not a normal practice of mine, just added to track down this leak)

```
     GC.Collect(2);
     GC.Collect(1);
     GC.Collect(0);
     GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
     GC.Collect();
     GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

I can go on like this for an hour, constantly leaking these objects.  Not seeing one single call to the finalizer/dispose implementation.  All of which is eliminated if I just don't pass it in `NavigationParameters`.

I've downloaded the PRISM code from GitHub.  I don't see it caching anything during `RequestNavigate` (nor would I expect to).  I don't see any issue with the `NavigationParameters` class itself either.  Whatever I give it just stored as `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`

```
public abstract class ParametersBase : IParameters, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    private readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> _entries = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
```

I even know that the parameters object itself does get cleaned up because to test it, I derived a class from `NavigationParameters` and made it implement `IDisposable` and used *that* to pass my parameters, just to log that it happens.   They do get cleaned up.  By my object that I put inside of them still did not.

At this point I am at a loss as for what to try.  I feel I've brought Prism into this unfairly and that it has nothing to do with that framework.  But I have stripped down my code so far to try to isolate the problem and cannot get beyond this point.  Can any memory leak gurus tell me what to try here?  Is there way to tell ***why*** my object is not being disposed?

(Edited to add: This is .NET 6 and Prism 8.1.97)

Comment: Am I missing something? The garbage collector will never dispose unless you implement a finalizer (which you shouldn't except in exceptional circumstances)

Comment: I did implement a Finalizer.  That is how I know it is not being disposed.  Because the Finalizer is not being invoked.  That's where I put the loggng/breakpoints, to test.

Comment: You can use dotmemory, for example, to inspect which references keep your objects alive. Events are a good candidate, the subscriber lives at least as long as the publisher (unless you use weak events)

Comment: Oh Cool.  Turns out I have Resharper Ultimate so I've got that.  Guess I need to learn how to use it now.  Thanks.  I think I really just needed someone to point me in the right direction.